# Big JSON file - how to compress in the server and decompress in the client side?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a json file that is approximately 2-3 MB in size. I want to compress this json in the server side when we are sending to client and decompress in the client side.

My Client is built on AngularJS SPA and getting the json output from Web API.

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": 25,
  "address":
  {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021"
  },
  "phoneNumber":
  [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "fax",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can compress on the server side. You dont need decompression on the client side. for compression you may run any javascript minifier. that should help

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Compression](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx) feature in IIS.

Aditionally, think about use of pagination to get the partial data.

Comment: This is what we are using now for our REST services with large result sets.

Comment: I need to do compression in C#(Web API) side and need to do decompression in Javascript side. Any thought ?